# How to get SpriteKit PhysicsBodies from .tmx TileMap file

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

My desired usage is this:

1. Create a .tmx map using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/index.html) that specifies the background and the starting location of a bunch of what will become `PhysicsBody` objects in SpriteKit
2. Use [JSTileMap](https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap) to read the .tmx and display it
3. Within the tilemap object that JSTileMap makes, reference the appropriate layers/objects/whatever to turn into various `PhysicsBody` objects, whose position is now controlled by the physics engine

I've successfully done 1. and 2. above but I'm stuck on 3. I can reference a layer or object, but when I even try a simple test to change its position (using the `setPosition` method), it crashes.

I'm very open to using something other than JSTileMap if that would make the ultimate goal of getting manipulatable layers/objects from a .tmx easier.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the maintainer of JSTileMap.  I have a sample project I did about a month ago that has some examples of what you're talking about here.  You are welcome to have a look at my code:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14626689/Platformer%20Test%201.zip

It should give you most of the answers you are looking for as well as having some slight tweaks to JSTileMap that are as yet unpublished.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was hoping you'd see my post. I'll download that project and try it out later tonight. I've also looked at Kobolkit but your solution seems more seamless with SpriteKit -- adding useful functionality without requiring subclassing something else.

Comment: I have to say this was exactly what I needed. While building a game I thought about using tile maps and jstilemap but wasn't quite sure how I was going to apply the physics. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample project that slycrel provided, it looks like this is the code snippet relevant to address my question:

```
TMXLayerInfo* layerInfo = [self.tileMap.layers firstObject];
        CGPoint pt = CGPointMake(a, b);
        NSInteger gid = [layerInfo.layer tileGidAt:[layerInfo.layer pointForCoord:pt]];
        if (gid == 2)
        {
            SKSpriteNode* node = [layerInfo.layer tileAtCoord:pt];
            node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.frame.size];
            node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        }
```

Unfortunately, it looks like something is wrong with the gids. `_gid_data` is `nil`. `currentFirstGID` shows up as 0. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this figured out?  I came by to drop a note in here about some of the new APIs that may help you that are currently in the iOS 7.1 beta API change notes.  They would make things more efficient without a lot of changes to my sample code.  If you're still working on this that may be worth a look.

Comment: I didn't figure this bit out. I looked at what I was trying to do again and decided that I was reaching for solutions that added a lot more complexity than I needed. I made my own level editor in java that just exports a csv file with the object type, xPosition, yPosition, and objectProperty and a 15 line interpreter in my game was all I needed.